# Problem in Trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger

```
trigger CopyAttachmentsToCon on Attachment (after insert) {

Set<Id> AccountIds = new Set<Id>();
for(Attachment file : Trigger.new) {

    if(file.ParentId.getSObjectType() == Account.getSObjectType()) {
        AccountIds.add(file.ParentId);
    }
}

if(AccountIds!=null && !AccountIds.isEmpty()){
    list<contact> tempList = [select id from contact where id in : AccountIds];
    if(tempList!=null && !tempList.isEmpty()){
        for(contact con : tempList){
            Attachment obj = new Attachment();
            obj.ParentId = con.id;
        }

    }
}
```

Trying to copy same inserted attachment on account object to its related contact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are querrying Contact where id you comparing is of acccount.

Quickfix would be to compare AccountID in where clause.

```
  Trigger CopyAttachmentsToCon on Attachment(after insert) {

      Set < Id > AccountIds = new Set < Id > ();
      Map < String, List < Attachment >> accountIDvsAttachmentList = new Map < String, List < Attachment >> ();
      for (Attachment file: Trigger.new) {

       if (file.ParentId.getSObjectType() == Account.getSObjectType()) {
        AccountIds.add(file.ParentId);

        //Adding attachment to Map
        if (accountIDvsAttachmentList.containsKey(file.ParentId)) {
         (accountIDvsAttachmentList.get(file.ParentID)).add(file);
        } else {
         accountIDvsAttachmentList.put(file.ParentID, new List < Attachment > {
          file
         });

        }

       }
      }
      if (AccountIds != null && !AccountIds.isEmpty()) {
       //Query wrt AccountID and not id
       list < contact > tempList = [select id, AccountID from contact where AccountID in : AccountIds];
       List < Attachment > attachmentsToBeInserted = new List < Attachment > ();
       if (tempList != null && !tempList.isEmpty()) {
        for (contact con: tempList) {
         if (accountIDvsAttachmentList.containsKey(con.AccountID)) {
          for (Attachment attached: accountIDvsAttachmentList.get(con.AccountID)) {

           Attachment obj = new Attachment();
           obj.ParentId = con.id;
           obj.body = attached.body;
           obj.name = attached.name;
           attachmentsToBeInserted.add(obj);
          }
         }
        }
        insert attachmentsToBeInserted;

       }
      }
```

Comment: Thanx! Now I got the Idea, Its working.